# C# Redirect to action with data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out how to use my Return RedirectToAction  to send it to my other view in a different controller with parameters.

I have the following code

```
return RedirectToAction("Notice", "?Redirect=Notice");
```

I would basically like to go to mywebsite.com/?Redirect=Notice/Notice

Could anyone please advise how to do so?

Comment: Is there a extra `Notice`? `Redirect=Notice/Notice`

Comment: I dont understand your question...sorry. Could you possibly rephrase that?

Comment: `RedirectToAction` will redirect to a "Controller/Action" combination.  The "Home/Index" combination by default is shortened to "/".  If you want to redirect to something else, use something other than `RedirectToAction()`

Comment: `return Redirect(Url.Content("~") + "?Redirect=Notice/Notice");`

Comment: @user2094139: sorry, forget about it. I thought there was a typo on your question

Comment: @MattHouser Thank you so much Matt! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` will redirect to a "Controller/Action" combination.  The "Home/Index" combination by default is shortened to "/".  If you want to redirect to something else (for example, the root of your website, use something other than `RedirectToAction()`.

For example:

```
return Redirect(Url.Content("~") + "?Redirect=Notice/Notice");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why @ClaudioRedi deleted his answer but it was correct:

```
return RedirectToAction("Notice", new { Redirect = "Notice/Notice" } );
```

If that takes you to the wrong URL, then that's due to using the wrong action name. I'm not sure how you have referenced your home page, but you should be using something along the lines of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Redirect = "Notice/Notice" } );
```

To reach the root of your site.